# modify program of generation for saving words in list and choosing them with random.choice()

Tags: python

How to modify program of generation for saving words in list and choosing them with `random.choice()` previously do  `import random`?

where is mistake? its not working correct

```
def generate_model(cfdist,word,num=15):
    for i in range(num):
        word=random.choice.im_class(cfdist
                        [word].keys())


>>> generate_model(cfd,'living')
```

Comment: You're going to have to show more code there, buddy. What is cfdist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is all kinds of weird stuff going on with that code:

```
def generate_model(cfdist,word,num=15):
```

You use word as the key to look up in the dictionary.

```
    word=
```

Then you change it? Are you intentionally chaining the result of one random lookup as the key for the next lookup?

```
random.choice
```

If you're intentionally chaining, this is right, but if you want a bunch of words from the same `dict` you want `random.sample`.

```
.im_class(
```

This is completely unnecessary. Just call it like `random.choice(`. Look at the examples in the [`random` docs](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html)

```
cfdist[word]
```

You're getting the value in `cfdist` with the key equal to the value of `word` passed in (in this case, `living`) the first time, then the key is equal to the result of the `choice` after that. Is that what you intended?

```
.keys())
```

This will work, if each value in `cfdist` is a `dict`.

Now, you say you want

> for saving words in list

But since I'm not sure what exactly you want, I'll give two examples. The first, I'll just aggregate the words, but not change anything else:

```
def generate_model(cfdist,word,num=15):
    words = []
    # you can add the starting word with words.append(word) here if you want
    for i in range(num):
        word=random.choice(cfdist[word].keys())
        words.append(word)
    return words
```

The second, I'll assume you just want 15 random words from the `dict` with no repetitions:

```
def generate_model(cfdist,word,num=15):
    return random.sample(cfdist[word].keys(), num)
```

Then either way call it as

```
>>> words = generate_model(cfd,'living')
```

to get the list of words.